# Laravel - Foreach in session and get attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently making a system where I'm working with sessions before I put the values in the database to prevent the mess. Now I have a small problem. If the user gets to a certain controller, All the values that were stored in the session need to be stored in the database. My sessions look like this:

[image]

If the GIF is too small, here is an imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmBFY.jpg

Now I need to have a foreach loop that loops through all the themes and products sessions and get their price and ID. But because they're stored in the session I have no clue how to retrieve them.

I store them in the session like this:

**Themes**

```
$theme = Product::find($selectedTheme);

    foreach($this->predefinedArray as $value) {
        $request->session()->put('chosen_theme.' . $value, $theme->$value);
    }
```

**Plugins**

```
foreach($request->input('plugin') as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === 'selected') {
            $selectedPlugin = $key;

            $plugin = Product::find($selectedPlugin);

            $price += $plugin->price;

            echo "ID: " . $plugin->id . "<br>";
            $selectedPlugins[$plugin->id] = $plugin->toArray();

            $request->session()->put('chosen_plugins.' . 'PluginID' . $plugin->id, $plugin->toArray());
            $request->session()->put('chosen_plugins.' . 'PluginID' . $plugin->id .'.composer_package', $plugin->productable->composer_package);

        }
    }
```

I know how to get a value out of a single session, like this `$themePrice = Session::get('chosen_theme')['price'];` But I don't know how to loop through a session with arrays

This is as far as I got

```
foreach( It needs to loop through all the sessions ) {

       $orderItems = new Orderitems;

        $orderItems->order_id = $order->id;
        $orderItems->product_id = ;
        $orderItems->price = ;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to merge both the `chosen_theme` and `chosen_plugins` session data together before using `foreach`.

Consider creating a new variable `$products = Session::get('chosen_plugins')`. This is a multi dimensional array.

Then add the `chosen_theme` array to `$products` using `$products['theme'] = Session::get('chosen_theme')`. This is done with the assumption there is only one `chosen_theme` and it is a one dimensional array.

The structure should now look like this:

```
[
    'pluginid1' => [...],
    'pluginid2' => [...],
    'pluginid3' => [...],
    'pluginid4' => [...],
    'theme' => [...]
];
```

Then, you should be able to run your loop:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $model = new Model;
    $model->price = $product['price'];
    ...
}
```

All the best.